# why is executing a command in the sh terminal failing

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I am using ubuntu.
When I do this from the terminal

`echo $SHELL`

I got `/bin/bash`

and then when I do

```
echo "`$SHELL -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`"
```

I got `4.4.20(1)-release`

Then, I try to do the same thing inside a particular docker container I am running, but as you will see this has the sh terminal not the bash terminal

so from that container

`echo $SHELL`

I got `/bin/sh`

that I have read is a link to `dash`

then with

`echo $BASH_VERSION`

I got
`4.3.48(1)-release`

so I do

```
echo "`$SHELL -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`"
```

and I got nothing.

1. Can someone explain me what is happening?
2. How can you run a sh terminal in ubuntu
3. Any aditional resource to understand shells is welcome too

I *specially* don't understand why when doing the `echo $BASH_VERSION` I got something but then with the latter I got nothing if the shell is the same

Comment: The docker container does not necessarily have the same components as your Ubuntu installation. What is the image that you are running on that container? You can also attach to it with `docker exec -ti <container_id> bash` and check what is in it.

Comment: I did and that is how I wrote the question. That is how I know the shell is sh

Comment: So If you know that the shell is `sh`, why are you trying to get the bash version? Obviously, you will get nothing

Comment: `that I have read is a link to dash` Where you have "read" it? `but then with the latter I got nothing if the shell is the same` So maybe, just maybe, the shell _is not_ the same? `and I got nothing.` Did you got nothing or did you get one empty line? did you get an error message? What is the content of `$SHELL` variable? What "particular docker container" are you using? Please post an [MCVE]?